# A good summary/explanation of Sql Server Express 2008 versions available for download?

Tags: sql-server-2008-express, sql-server-2008r2-express

Can someone tell me whether this link that I used to install Sql Server Express 2008 is version R2 or not? I installed from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22973

The reason that I ask is that I am trying to setup an unattended installation of Sql Server Express 2008 and have found the following tutorial:

http://sqlbeyond.blogspot.com/2011/07/sql-server-express-2008-r2-unattended.html

The link that it mentions though has the word "beta" in it which makes me think that this link might be out of date. So can someone tell me firstly what version I have installed and secondly where I can download 64 bit and 32 bit versions of Sql Server Express 2008 for deployment (so no tools, etc). Thanks.

Update:

I suspect that the version I installed was RC0. The fact that the heading of the Microsoft page does not spell it out or provide links to new releases is not very helpful at all. Anyway, I have found the following page, which I think is what I am needing:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26729

and I found this explanation about the different versions of Sql Server Express 2008 file names which was very helpful:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/08/22/the-sql-express-2008-family-is-getting-bigger.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I know it is a lousy question, the worst I have ever asked, and earned me my first down vote... I guess I am just peaking in frustration at the moment. Searching on google for Microsoft products give you a maze similar sounding downloads and trying to find the differences between them can be very frustrating. If someone can provide a useful link that provides a summary of the different versions of Sql Server 2008 that are available, then maybe something good can come out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try answer my own question. I found this link which I find useful for getting an overview of the different Sql Server versions:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-versions

I assume that because Sql Server Express is an edition of Sql Server that its version numbers are identical to Sql Server version numbers. Sql Server Express 2008 R2, then, must have a version number matching the pattern 10.50.x.x, and the version that I originally downloaded from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22973

is therefore the original release of Sql Server Express 2008; so without SP1 or SP2.

I also found this useful link which explains how to determine the version for an installed instance of Sql Server:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/euanga/archive/2008/01/23/confused-by-sql-server-version-numbers.aspx